# Time derivative of the commutator of two operators $P,L$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-operators

I am reading a textbook [Mathematics for Physics](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf). In page 126, the author defines two operators:
$$L=-\partial_x^2+q(x)$$
$$P=\partial_x^3+a(x)\partial_x+\partial_x a(x)$$
Then the author continues to calculate the commutator, which as I understand has the same definition from ring theory:
$$[P,L]=PL-LP$$
After some tedious calculations and setting $a(x)=-\frac 34 q(x)$, the following equation is reached.
$$[P,L]=\frac 14 q'''-\frac 32 qq'$$
The part where I don't understand is, the author then writes:
$$\frac {dL}{dt} = [P,L]$$
or, equivalently
$$\dot q = \frac 14 q'''-\frac 32 qq'$$
I think I may lack specific knowledge on this part as why we can set the time derivative $\frac{dL}{dt} = [P,L]$ and what is the author trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the page. The authors do not obtain this result. The give an example (KdV) of an equation written as
$$
\frac{dL}{dt}=[P,L],\;\;\;(1)
$$
for operators $L$ and $P$. These equations are part of the class of PDEs that have a "Lax pair". Among its properties, as shown in the book, is the fact that the eigenvalues of $L$ are constant in time.

Another way to see (1) is that it comes from the compatibility condition for the system of two linear questions in "$u$":
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=Pu\\
\lambda u=Lu.
$$
We usually call the system above the "Lax Pair". We compute the compatibility condition of the system above by multiplying the first one by $\lambda$ and taking the derivative wrt time of the second one. One the two LHS's, we get in both cases $\lambda du/dt$. Equating the two right sides, one gets (1).

Comment: Upon checking [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_pair), I see that equation (1) is just from the definition of Lax pair.